# jsonをjavascriptで取得しhtmlに表示したい

Tags: javascript, html, json, rest

現在 http://garafu.blogspot.jp/2013/08/wcf-restful-web.html を参考に、
jsonからのデータを取得しhtmlに表示したいと考えています。

イメージとしては、下記の画像の入力欄に名前を入力しOKボタンを押下すると、
表示欄にjsonのデータが出力されるような感じです。

そこで、html上でrestを送る方法と、jsonのデータを取得する方法が分かりません。
宜しければご教授をお願いします。

[image: 画面]

Comment: 分からない場所は具体的に言うとどのあたりでしょうか？

Comment: 説明不足で申し訳ありません
html上でrestを送る方法と、jonのデータを取得する方法が分からない感じです

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jqueryを利用した最もシンプルな方法は以下になります。

```
var name = $("[ここに入力欄のinputのセレクタ]").val();

$.get("[ここにjsonを返すURLを入力]", {name: name}, function(data){
  $("[ここに表示欄のinputのセレクタ]").val(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

HTTP通信の種類を指定して実行するには以下になります。

```
var name = $("[ここに入力欄のinputのセレクタ]").val();

$.ajax({
  url: "[ここにjsonを返すURLを入力]",
  data: {name: name},
  type: "[ここにHTTP通信の種類（POST,PUT,DELETEなど）を入力]"
}).done(function(data){
  $("[ここに表示欄のinputのセレクタ]").val(data);
});
```

非同期で実行したくない場合は以下になります。

```
var name = $("[ここに入力欄のinputのセレクタ]").val();

var data = $.ajax({
  url: "[ここにjsonを返すURLを入力]",
  data: {name: name},
  type: ”[ここにHTTP通信の種類（POST,PUT,DELETEなど）を入力]",
  async: false
}).responseText;

$("[ここに表示欄のinputのセレクタ]").val(data);
```

Comment: 補足事項として、 jQuery の ajax() を使う場合は `type: PUT` や `type:DELETE` の指定を追加することすることによって、HTTP通信の種類を変更することも可能です。(質問者さんが REST で、と仰ってるので言及させて頂きました)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。反映させていただきましたm(_ _)m

Comment: `async=false`は同期リクエストだと思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。m(_ _)m

Comment: 解決することが出来ました。
ありがとうございます。